# Convert string to timestamp in hive when creating a table

Tags: hadoop, hive, timestamp, bigdata, hiveql

I have some realtime data in CSVs. I want to create external tables from this data so that I can query it from hive. The challenge is that, these files have unix epoch as `last_updated_epoch` and a date field `last_updated` which is formatted as `2021-08-04T06:48:55`. I cannot read this date as timestamp, so I need to convert these fields into timestamps to query based on date and time.

***What I am able to do:*** I am able to create a table with timestamp as BIGINT and `last_updated` as string. But cannot make `last_updated` as timestamp when creating the table. Select works fine:

```
select last_updated, cast(from_unixtime(last_updated_epoch) as TIMESTAMP) from station_mart limit 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is  :-

1. Have your external table with the data type as you want.
2. Land your csv files on a different location.
3. Use load data inpath command to load the data first into a temporary table from
   the landing location, then
   use insert into command to insert the data into the external table from the
   temporary table.While loading this data into the external table you can
   transform your data as you want.
4. To handle the real time data, you can create a script of step 2 and step 3 then
   schedule it at an interval less then your SLA , this will give you data at real
   time.

Load data inpath command moves the data, so you dont have to worry about data duplication.

Answer (score 0):

I propose three different methods to convert your string to timestamp. First two applicable if your table is defined other than STORED AS TEXTFILE, third method works if you can use LazySimpleSerDe (the same as STORED AS TEXTFILE), in this case SerDe will do conversion on the lowest possible livel.

**Conversion in the select:**

```
select last_updated as original_last_updated, --initial string 

       --1st method (preferable, because it is not using SimpleDateFormat(which is really not so simple) class internally)
       --you can additionally apply timestamp() construct, though in Hive String in proper format is fully interchangeable
       regexp_replace(last_updated,'^(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2})T(\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2})','$1 $2') as result1, 

       --2nd method is using SimpleDateFormat under the hood, easier to read
       from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(last_updated,"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")) as result2
from
(select '2021-08-04T06:48:55' as last_updated ) s
```

Result:

```
original_last_updated         result1                result2
2021-08-04T06:48:55           2021-08-04 06:48:55    2021-08-04 06:48:55
```

**3rd method - Using LazySimpleSerDe:**

**if you are using LazySimpleSerDe** (STORED AS TEXTFILE), alternative timestamp formats can be supported by providing the format to the SerDe property `"timestamp.formats"` (as of release 1.2.0 with [HIVE-9298](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-9298)). Try `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"` as property value and define column type as `timestamp`. Though LazySimpleSerDe does not recognize quotes and can be used in cases when you have simple CSV with unquoted values.